# Create a pdf or other file type from file content fetched from API

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, blazor

I consume a web service that supports documents as attachments.
I can get the filename, file content, mime type etc but I can't make it into a working file. I try to open the file on my computer but it's corrupted somehow.

The document I'm getting is a pdf in this case so I've tried to hard code the extension just to get it working. After this I'll try to get the extension from the mime-type, but that's not the problem right now. Right now I simply can't open the created file in a PDF reader, and I need to make that work.

I've tried the following code:

```
    void CreateFileFromDocumentContent(string content, string fileName)
{
    string destinationFile = @"wwwroot/" + fileName + ".pdf";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(destinationFile);

    try
    {
        // Create a new file     
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(destinationFile))
        {
            // Add some text to file    
            Byte[] fileContent = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(content);
            fs.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        }

        // Write file contents on console.     
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(destinationFile))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(s);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm writing the file contents to the console.
It looks something like JVBERi0xLjMNCiX/////MTI3NQ0KMSAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nDQovUGFnZXMgNCAwIFINCi9PdXRsaW5lcyAyIDAgUg0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMiAwIG9iag0KPDwNC..... and it's probably the file content itself as if you were to open the pdf in notepad. It looks the same as the webservice file contents.

I've tried to write the file as pure text (not bytes like in my code example) but it doesn't work either.

I'm guessing something is missing. This webservice is also used by a third party software and looking up the same file works fine in their solution, so the file itself is good.

Comment: Without knowing more, I'm pretty sure that the answer from the API isn't a UTF-8 encoded string that represents the PDF file. Rather, it's probably a base64 string representing the raw bytes that make up the file. Use the [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0) method and save the raw bytes to the file

Comment: Good observation. That did the trick! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, I decided to post an answer below, seeing as how my guess turned out to be correct

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies not with the API or how the file is being saved, but with how the string content is being turned into the contents of the file itself. PDF is not a text based format (citation needed), instead it's raw bytes in a specific format so that PDF readers can open it. Meaning, simply converting to bytes sent into UTF-8 encoded text and saving them is not correct. Instead, the string in the response body is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded, a way to represent memory as a string, and as such needs to be decoded into raw bytes to be saved. Luckily C#/ .NET has a built in method to do it, like so:

```cs
byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
```